# Exact usage of Async.Sleep() in F#

Tags: asynchronous, f#

I have a question:

I have problem in usage Async.Sleep() method in F#. This is a piece of code in my program:

```
if (newAngle <> currentAngle) then
    if (newAngle = 0) then
        Motor(MotorPort.OutA).SetSpeed(100y)
        angle1 <- Motor(MotorPort.OutA).GetTachoCount()
        **Async.Sleep(20)**
        angle2 <- Motor(MotorPort.OutA).GetTachoCount()
        speed <- abs(angle2 - angle1)
        distance <- abs(newAngle - angle2)
        if (speed > 11) then
            pwr <- 20L + int64 distance
            if (pwr < 100L) then
                Motor(MotorPort.OutA).SetSpeed(sbyte pwr)
        while (distance > 30 || angle2 <> angle1) do
            angle1 <- Motor(MotorPort.OutA).GetTachoCount()
            **Async.Sleep(20)**
            angle2 <- Motor(MotorPort.OutA).GetTachoCount()
            speed <- abs(angle2 - angle1)
            distance <- abs(newAngle - angle2)
            if (speed > 11) then
                pwr <- 20L + int64 distance
                if (pwr < 100L) then
                    Motor(MotorPort.OutA).SetSpeed(sbyte pwr)
        Motor(MotorPort.OutA).Off() //? off
        **Async.Sleep(300)**
```

I have used Async.Sleep() function in some places in my code. But unfortunately, when I use Async.Sleep() method I get this error:

```
This expression was expected to have type unitbut here has type Async<unit>
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: `Async.Sleep` is intended to be used within `async { }` blocks, not at arbitrary places in normal code.

Comment: This time it shows this error: This expression was expected to have type
    unit    
but here has type
    Async<'a>

Comment: This code has another problem: using Async.Sleep or Thread.Sleep for timing will not work well on time-scales below 0.5s, as the sleeping time-span will differ from the requested time-span. Using the [Stopwatch class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) before and after sleeping should yield more reliable measurements of elapsed time.

Comment: They haven't shown any example, could you show me any example @Vandroiy?

Comment: I have the feeling that you are having trouble with too many concepts at once, so it becomes unclear what the exact problem is. It might help to do some F# exercises, read examples, and get some routine. Before you remove compiler errors, you should try to understand them. *(The stopwatch is really straightforward: before the operation you want to time, create and start it via `Stopwatch.StartNew()`. Afterwards, `.Stop()` it and use `.ElapsedMilliseconds` to get the passed time. It seems my earlier comment was only half right: `Async.Sleep` is much less precise than `Thread.Sleep`.)*

Comment: @yusuf : _You_ clearly do not understand async blocks; maybe a bit of introspection is needed here rather than blaming the people who cannot make sense of your misconceptions/misunderstandings, eh?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Async.sleep` gives back some "`async`" code.

The "`async`" computation expression builder allows to inject computations to a new type, `async<_>`, and ***weave*** such computations in a way which does not block a single thread, by relying on the threadpool and knowing how to suspend (and resume !) computations in a efficient way.

The bottom line is that the main benefit is the controlled **weaving** (and - different aspect - controled execution) of such computations.

If you just need one `Async` instruction, there is no weaving, and no benefit in using the `async<_>` type. As suggested, you propably want to use the `Thread.Sleep`

The best way to learn about those async is to unsugar the `async` computation expression into its succession of callback. every computation expression is compiled to that form.

Then you can look at the specific operations invoked, which are specific to the `async` computation expression builder.

--

Unfortunately, while F# `async` make everything possible to make it simple to use, such feature is nonetheless not trivial, and require some time to understand.

I suggest you look at it as a subject on its own first, and not go for a quick fix. 
The good part is that it is quite instructive to understand this technique as it uses more general mechanism like computation expression !

Answer (score 7):

You need a `do!` before the call to `Async.Sleep`, i.e.

```
async{
    ...
    do! Async.Sleep(time * 1000)
    ...
}
```

How to research this on your own next time:

1. [Bing "Async.Sleep"](http://www.bing.com/search?q=Async.Sleep)
2. [First result](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370508.aspx) - MSDN docs for F# Async.Sleep
3. Look at example code.

Comment: This time it shows this error: This expression was expected to have type
    unit    
but here has type
    Async<'a>

Comment: @yusuf : You're not calling it from within an async block; maybe you want `Thread.Sleep`?

Comment: Yes it does. Just like you need `using System.Threading;` in C#, you need `open System.Threading` in F#.  Or fully-qualify with `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)`.

Comment: The issue is that whatever function has this `Async` in it, is now returning an `Async` object and the expectation is clearly that it will return `unit`. See here for a possible resolution: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353487.aspx

Answer (score 2):

`Async.Sleep` returns an `async` computation. All you have to do is just run it and wait until it finishes:

```
Async.Sleep(5000) |> Async.RunSynchronously
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
open System.Threading

//and wherever requires write the below mentioned code
Thread.Sleep(20000) //20000 in Milliseconds unit
```